# Why the first argument of argv is 1 not 0

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have some parameters to the program work correctly. This arguments shoud be, MAX_NUM, x, y.

When catching the parameters of the char input list, I currently obtain MAX_NUM using the argument 1 instead of 0.

Ex:

```cpp
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int MAX_NUM = atoi(argv[0]);
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    int t = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("MAX_NUM %d\n", atoi(argv[0]));
....
```

Priting *argv[1]* i get the MAX_NUM correctly, when printing the first argument gets 0.

Why C init the char input list array on 1 instead of 0 or the program name?

Comment: The arg[0] is the program path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple terms, the value of `argv[0]` is the name of the program to execute. C *kinda* reserves the `argv[0]` index for this purpose. To get into some nitty-gritty details of how C and your operating system start to work with each other - check out this post in [Stack Overflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315812/why-does-argv-include-the-program-name).